# How to "create" a file in NodeJS v16

Tags: node.js, file, system, fs, createfile

I tried making an evaluate command with discordjs and im trying to log the code in a file.

This is my code rn:

```js
const { Client, MessageEmbed, MessageAttachment } = require('discord.js');
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');
const { inspect } = require('util');
module.exports = {
  name : "evaluate",
  aliases : ['eval'],
  description: "This command allows the developer to execute a code!",
  run : async (client, messageCreate, args) => {

  if(messageCreate.author.id !== '754165961946562601') return;

  try {
    const code = args.join(" ");
    if (!code) {
       return messageCreate.channel.send("Please Provide A code to eval!");
    }
    let evaled = await eval(code);

    if (typeof evaled !== "string")
       evaled = require("util").inspect(evaled);
       const output = await evaled.substring(0,1000)
       const input = await code.substring(0,1000)
    let embed = new MessageEmbed()
       .setAuthor("Eval", messageCreate.author.avatarURL())
       .addField("Input", `\`\`\`${input}\`\`\``)
       .addField("Output", `\`\`\`${output}\`\`\``)
       .setColor("GREEN");

    messageCreate.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] })
    .then(msg => {
        setTimeout( () => {
        msg.delete()
        }, 10000
        )
        });
 } catch (err) {
    messageCreate.channel.send(`\`ERROR\` \`\`\`js\n${err}\n\`\`\``);
 }

 const data = await axios.get('http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Kolkata')
fs.writeFileSync(`./eval-logs/eval-${data.data.datetime}.txt`, "exodus")
    }



  }
```

Everything works, but it returns the error that the file is not found. Now I want it to create a file named  `eval-${data.data.datetime}.txt` in eval-logs command. Can i even do it?

Answer (score 0):

The error most probably comes from the fact that the path leading to the file does not exist. You should try to log `process.cwd()` to check what is NodeJS current directory and verify that the folder in which you want to create the file exists with `fs.access`, or create it with `fs.mkdir`.

Note that you should avoid using synchronous APIs to access the file system as it will freeze your execution. Since you already are in an asynchronous function, I would recommend using the `fs.promises` module of NodeJS, and replace `fs.writeFileSync(...)` by `await fs.promises.writeFile(...)`